# mocking sleep in a test

Tags: python-2.7, mocking, patch, pytest

I have a function to test that eventually calls another function which has some time.sleep functions in it. I do not want my test to sleep. So, my question is, is it better to mock the test function, or wrap my call to the function to test with a patch?

Example 1

```
@patch('time.sleep')
def test_some_function(mock_time):
    data = some_sleepy_function()
    assert data == expected_data
```

Example 2:

```
def test_some_function():
    @patch('time.sleep')
    def run_function(mock_sleep):
        return some_sleepy_function()
    assert run_function() == expected_data
```

Comment: Um, what answer are you expecting that is not "it depends"?

Comment: maybe it depends on what? I was wondering if one way was preferred over another way

Comment: it depends on what your program and the other function does. Most probably there was a reason that function included a sleep, but you don't mention it. On that base, it's hard to tell you what you should do, and your question is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mock something simple like `time.sleep` I would use py.test's `monkeypatch`:

```
def test_some_function(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(time, 'sleep', lambda s: None)
    data = some_sleepy_function()
    assert data == expected_data
```

If you are grouping your tests in a class:

```
class Test:

    def test_some_function(self, monkeypatch):
        monkeypatch.setattr(time, 'sleep', lambda s: None)
        data = some_sleepy_function()
        assert data == expected_data
```

Notice that this is only valid for "standard" pytest classes (not `unittest.TestCase` subclasses).

Using `mock.patch` as decorator together with pytest is confusing in my opinion because py.test's fixtures are passed as arguments to test functions.

Comment: I actually have a test class. The test that needs the sleep mocked is a member function. I tried to add the monkeypatch parameter to the function signature, but I get test_some_function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

My function is like this:
def test_some_function(self):

How do I pass monkeypatch to that? (I have not use monkeypatch before)

Comment: Added an example using a test class

Comment: in my case it doesn't slow down the sleep